# Configure SQL Test with Teamcity integration

Tags: sql-server, unit-testing, teamcity, redgate, tsqlt

I am using SQL Test to create some unit tests in SQL Server. And I integrated with Teamcity so that on a build, it auto runs the tSQLt tests.

The issue is that we plan to create hundreds of unit tests for all our store procs. And we don't want to run all of the unit tests each time we check in code and whereby Teamcity runs a build + runs all the unit tests.

Is there a way to configure the integration build to only run the new unit tests that are checked in. Would I need to create a custom script for this? I can't seem to find a way out of the box.

Or is the practical solution to check in without Teamcity auto running the tSQLt unit tests? Thereby, just manually run the new test cases on the DEV server (after check in)? An extension of this is to run a batch nightly to run ALL the unit tests.

Answer (score 5):

Is there a particular reason that you don't want all tests to be run on the build server every time there is a check-in?

We have over 1000 tSQLt tests in the project I am currently working on and another 3000 code tests.  All our tests run each time there is a check-in.

I don't use SQL Test to write my tSQLt tests anymore as I have integrated my database unit testing into my Visual Studio project. I have a T4 template that creates NUnit wrappers around my tSQLt tests and as far as my build server is concerned it is just running a set of regular NUnit tests when it runs the tSQLt unit tests. This means I can use NUnit categories etc to control what tests are run on the build server and when they should be run (i.e. every time, only during the nightly build) if I chose to.

For an example of how I do this see (https://github.com/chilli-andrew/).  This may not fit your workflow, but it's worth a look to get a different perspective as to how you can work with tSQLt.

Comment: thanks for the note. How long does it take to run 1000+ tSQLt tests? We expect to have about 500 unit tests and were concerned about the additional build time during check-in (by running all unit tests vs just the new ones). With 4 programmers, we  were concerned about a long build cycle to avoid possible conflicts/delays on check-ins whereby a programmer may try to check in while a build is currently running (not sure if this would cause problems other than a delay). The other reason I guess is simply not to run things needlessly.

Comment: It takes about 40 minutes for the build and full test pack to run on the CI server.  There are about 4500 unit tests, spec flow tests and tSQLt tests. We also store our database schema and objects in Visual Studio database projects. These take a while to compile and to deploy schema changes to the testing databases (maybe 50% of the total time). The +-1000 tSQLt tests runon their own on my dev machine only take about 5 minutes to run.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than just running the new tests each time you could use [test classes](http://tsqlt.org/user-guide/test-creation-and-execution/newtestclass/) to separate out any 'tier 1' tests that you want to run on every check in, from other tests that you want to run less frequently.

A test class is created using a specific schema.  You could then use a SQL Compare/Source Control filter to exclude any schemas that you don't want to get tested on each commit.

That feels safer than only running the new tests.  If you only run new tests then you don't know if your change has broken existing functionality.

**Update:**
SQL CI and the Team City Plugin now let you specify any classes that you wanted to include/exclude, instead of just running tSQLt.RunAll.

Comment: "It would be much nicer if SQL CI and the Team City Plugin let you specify any classes that you wanted to include/exclude, instead of just running tSQLt.RunAll." >>> that's pretty much the idea. Would be nice to have.

Comment: But wouldn't this entail some additional steps? Say I used the "new" schema. Then used SQL Compare to only pull this schema which would then only run the unit tests with the "new" schema. But after a checkin, wouldn't I have to change the schema on DEV and also change it on my local so that it doesn't get pulled/runs again on the next checkin? Not sure if we want to add these extra steps.

Comment: You're right, in that it wouldn't help to just run new tests.  I'd avoid just running just the new tests for the reasons in my post above.  However it would let you run a defined subset of all tests, say those that you deem important to run on each commit.  You could have a different Team City build job (say run nightly) that runs all the tests for complete coverage.

Comment: Just a quick update.  SQL CI, along with the TeamCity and TFS plugins now allow you do this.

Comment: Jon, thanks for the update. Question: does the update reflect your comment about setting up test classes and being able to exclude? Or does the update reflect my original question on whether it can be set up to run only new test check ins. We run all the tests locally and we have a nightly batch that runs all the tests. So we ok with not running all the tests during a check in. The primary reason for only running new tests upon check in is to avoid a long checkin/build/run-all-tests step.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you are creating your tsqlt results for you CI server, but if you are using

```
EXEC tSQLt.RunWithXmlResults
```

to generate your test output, another possible option you could play around with is.

```
EXEC tSQLt.SetTestResultFormatter 'tsqlt.xmlresultformatter'
EXEC tSQLt.Run 'UnitTests_YourUnitTestClass'
EXEC tSQLt.SetTestResultFormatter 'tsqlt.defaultresultformatter'
```

Comment: There's also tSQLt.RunTestClass ClassName.